# Filter if function returns FALSE

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains a column with a comma separated list of words:

```
   df <- data.frame(gene=c("1", "2", "3", "4"), affected_genes = c("Rim2, CG18208", "ANB, XYZ", "Gene1, Gene2", "XYZ"))

 gene affected_genes
    1  Rim2, CG18208
    2       ANB, XYZ
    3   Gene1, Gene2
    4            XYZ
```

I want to filter out rows where `affected_genes` does not contain `XYZ`. Here's what I'm trying:

```
library(dplyr)

geneIn <- function(gene, gene_list){
    gene %in% sapply(gene_list, function(x) strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]], USE.NAMES=FALSE)
  }


df %>%
    dplyr::filter(geneIn("XYZ", affected_genes))
```

However this fails with `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: non-character argument.`

When I run:

```
affected_genes <- "ANB, XYZ"
geneIn("XYZ", affected_genes)
```

I get my expected result (`TRUE`). Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong in my first example?

Comment: I suggest you create some tidy data. Even a list column would be better than what you have now.

Comment: Your geneIn function should takes as input a vector of `affected_gene` and return a vector of booleans.

Comment: Any chance your affected_genes column is a factor instead of character? If you use your data but add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` it works fine. Well, not fine, but it doesn't give THIS error.

Comment: FYI you can simply do `df[grepl('\\bXYZ\\b', df$affected_genes),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: your `df$affected_genes` appear to be a factor, so either make them into char class (e.g., by including `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `read.table` call), or pass the column through `as.character` first. Second, you want to insert your `%in%` into the `sapply`, because otherwise you'll get a vector of length 1 as a response (it'll check if the gene appears anywhere in the list of all the individual gene names), instead of a TRUE/FALSE for each row. Overall the code of your function should be:

```
geneIn <- function(gene, gene_list) {
            sapply(as.character(gene_list), function(x) gene %in% strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]], USE.NAMES=FALSE)
          }
```

Which works well:

```
df %>% dplyr::filter(geneIn("XYZ", affected_genes))

  gene affected_genes
1    2       ANB, XYZ
2    4            XYZ
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have several genes in one character string. The "tidy data" concept as defined by Hadley Wickham would require this format:

```
gene affected_gene
   1          Rim2
   1       CG18208
   2           ANB
   2           XYZ
      ...
```

However, you should at least split the character strings and create a list column if you want to further analyze this data:

```
df$affected_genes <-  lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$affected_genes), ","), trimws)
df[vapply(df$affected_genes, `%in%`, x = "XYZ", FUN.VALUE = logical(1)),]
#  gene affected_genes
#2    2       ANB, XYZ
#4    4            XYZ
```

With the tidy format above, you wouldn't need an `*apply` loop.